# How to get name file when we select a file in 1C:Enterprise

Tags: erp

I'm currently using 1C:ERP and I'm writing a module to import data from Excel file, but I'm going to work with several types of Excel file, each of them has another file name, so I'm wondering how can we get the file name when we select a file

```
&AtClient
Procedure FillFromFile(Command)
    FileDialog = New FileDialog(FileDialogMode.Open);
    FileDialog.Title = "Choose file";
    FileDialog.Filter = "Tabular document|*.xlsx";
    NotifyDescription = New NotifyDescription("FillFromFile_NotifyDescription", ThisObject);
    FileDialog.Show(NotifyDescription);
EndProcedure

&AtClient
Procedure FillFromFile_NotifyDescription(SelectedFiles, AdditionalParameters) Export
    If SelectedFiles <> Undefined Then
        BinaryData = New BinaryData(SelectedFiles[0]);
        StorageFilePath = PutToTempStorage(BinaryData);
        FillFromFileAtServer(StorageFilePath, SelectedFiles[0]);
    EndIf;
EndProcedure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extra method GetNameFile(). For example, "C:\Users\1c\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel.xlsx"

```
    &AtServer
    Function GetNameFile(FileDirectory)
        Post = Find(FileDirectory,"\");
        While Post<>0 Do
            FileDirectory = Right(FileDirectory,StrLen(FileDirectory) - Post);
            Post = Find(FileDirectory,"\");
        EndDo;
        Return FileDirectory; 
    EndFunction
```

You will get "Excel" in return